# debugging typescript when calling an web api from angular

Tags: angular

I am very new in angular. I am trying to call my web API method from angular. I am getting an message loading... on my browser when I do the http.get request . I am assuming there is an error at http.get Below is my code

```
 getProjectDetails() {

    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/Index').pipe(map(
      response => {
        return response;
      }));

  }
```

I tried to trap the error by implementing handlerror in angular

```
 private handleError(operation: String) {
    return (err: any) => {
      let errMsg = `error in ${operation}() retrieving ${this.myAppUrl}`;
      console.log(`${errMsg}:`, err)
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        // you could extract more info about the error if you want, e.g.:
        console.log(`status: ${err.status}, ${err.statusText}`);
        // errMsg = ...
      }
      return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
  }
```

not sure, how to implement it in my method getProjectDetails()

Below is my entire code:

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AllItProject } from '../../models/allitproject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectDetailService {

  myAppUrl = '';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.myAppUrl = baseUrl;
  }

  private handleError(operation: String) {
    return (err: any) => {
      let errMsg = `error in ${operation}() retrieving ${this.myAppUrl}`;
      console.log(`${errMsg}:`, err)
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        // you could extract more info about the error if you want, e.g.:
        console.log(`status: ${err.status}, ${err.statusText}`);
        // errMsg = ...
      }
      return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
  }


  getProjectDetails() {

    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/Index').pipe(map(
      response => {
        return response;
      }));

  }
```

The error is coming somewhere when I do http.get. When I open the developers tools in the browser, I see the error :

"Http failure response for https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index: 500 OK".

Below is my controller method that I am trying to call

```
namespace ProjectDetails.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AllItProjectsListsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly KPIContext _context;
        private readonly IProject objProject;

        public AllItProjectsListsController(IProject _objProject)
        {
            objProject = _objProject;

        }


        [HttpGet("Index")]
        public IEnumerable<AllItProjectsList> Index()
        {
            return objProject.GetAllProjectDetails();
        }
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `.pipe(map(response => response))` is pointless.

Comment: are you sure you need /index?

Comment: I am learning angular by follwoing a tutorial and that person who wrote the article is using ..pipe(map(
      response => {
        return response; what else can I  use. I also put my.net core  controller class above to show which index method, i am trying to call.

Comment: Try `[HttpGet("/Index")]` or `[Route("Index")]` in your controller.

Comment: Try to debug your code. What happens if you navigate to `https://localhost:44313/api/AllItProjectsLists/Index` in the browser? Do you get a response with data or a 500?

Comment: No, when I navigate to this URL in the browser, my angular GUI comes up and when I do F12 then I see the 500 error. I posted the error above in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to see your error, you can use `catchError` to trap that, modify your service like the following :

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectDetailService {

  myAppUrl = '';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.myAppUrl = baseUrl;
  }

  getProjectDetails() {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'api/AllItProjectsLists/Index', this.setHttpHeader())
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log("Anlagenstatus Daten:", data)),
        catchError(this.handleError),
      )
  }

  private setHttpHeader() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json').set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = { headers: headers };
    return options;
  }

  private handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
    console.error("observable error: ", error);
    return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }

}
```

Now you can see your error in **the browser -> console tab**

If you got an error with status code `500`: It means there is an error in your server (Inspect your API)

Comment: I am getting an error "Cannot find name RequestOptions"

Comment: I am getting an error on both options and map saying "cannot find name options" and Property map does not exists on type observable.

Comment: @Anjali - look at this example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crahu8 (in the root of the project there is a service named ProjectDetailService)

Comment: Thank You. I am getting the error on the server side, but your error catching works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting internal server that means angular's httpclient able to hit the server but due to some issue in your server code... Server giving 500 Internal server error...

I would suggest you to verify your API using POST man tool... It will help you clear weather it's a server side code issue or angular side...

Moreover,  use Angular "observable" and "Subscribe" feature which help you get this fix quickly.

```
    /** GET heroes from the server */
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
}
```

For more details please follow the below link

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Let me know if you still facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

1. Are these constructor level injection registered somewhere or you are just injecting without any registration tool... like autofac, ninject etc.
2. Remove routing and all from API method or make a simple get method without any parameters and then hit the API from POSTMAN.

I hope this time you will definitely get your solution...